# Plone 4.3 Diazo — Bootstrap theme shows up randomly?

Tags: plone, diazo

I have a custom theme using a rules.xml and other files on one of our network servers. The "Twitter Bootstrap" theme is also installed (the one that's there by default) but isn't active. However, for some reason, when loading the website from a URL (http://chinaapple.ucdavis.edu), sometimes it still loads the Twitter Bootstrap theme, and sometimes it loads my theme but incompletely (unstyled elements).

[image: Bizarro!]

Any idea why this might happen? It seems to occur randomly, maybe one in ten refreshes. Is something cached weirdly? Or is there a way to completely disable the Bootstrap theme?

Here are my Diazo settings —

[image: Diazo settings]

And our system is set up with Apache2, HAProxy, and Plone 4.3. Thanks!

Comment: feesh! I can't reproduce this, unfortunately.

Comment: Doh! Bizarre, maybe something odd was cached. Sorry, thanks aclark! :)

Comment: Do you need to host the theme on a different server? Perhaps it's possible there are network issues.